# Can MDS only be installed on a server

Tags: sql, sql-server, iis, installation, mds

Can you run the SQL Server 2014 Master Data Services Configuration manager on windows 8.1 pro and not on a server like Windows server R2?

If so please help it tells me "The required .svc handler mappings are not installed in IIS." but I have checked and everything in the windows features under IIS is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a simple google search away.

You can run it on Windows 8.1 Pro.

Take a look at this link for several troubleshooting help:
[SVC_Handler_mapping_error_in_MDS_Configuration_Manager](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2390.sql-server-troubleshooting-master-data-services-installation-and-configuration.aspx#SVC_Handler_mapping_error_in_MDS_Configuration_Manager)

> SVC Handler mapping error in MDS Configuration Manager
>
> When you configure Master Data Services in the MDS Configuration
>   Manager, you may encounter an error indicating that the required .svc
>   handler mappings are not installed in IIS.
>
> Before creating an MDS web application, you must correct the following
>   errors:
>
> Internet Information Services (IIS) is not configured on this server.
>   The required .svc handler mappings are not installed in IIS.
>       This can occur in one of the following instances: IIS may be missing the necessary .svc Handler Mappings. Visit IIS Manager from
>   the start menu. If you have a default website listed, click the site,
>   and click Handler Mappers icon. In the list, sort by Path column.
>   notice if *.svc is listed or not. If it is already listed, this error
>   may a false positive, but if it is not, you may need to install the
>   *.svc path mappers in Step 2 & 3 below.
>
> Depending on the IIS version, there are different ways to get the
>   Service Mappers installed. For .Net 4.0, the mappers may need to be
>   installed by installing HTTP activation in .Net Framework 4.6 Advanced
>   Services.  From the start menu search or control panel, find the item
>   Turn Windows Features Off or On.  then in the tree of Windows Features
>   find .Net Framework 4.6 > WCF Services > HTTP Activation
>
> On earlier Windows versions where .Net Framework 4.0 does not come
>   preinstalled, when you add or install IIS features after .NET 4 was
>   installed, you may encounter this error. To fix this issue, open a
>   command prompt and go to the .NET directory (for example
>   %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319). Run the command:
>   aspnet_regiis -i.
>
> You may encounter this error as a false positive or false negative
>   when there is an existing IIS website(s) already existing in your IIS
>   server, but you select a different Web site to host MDS, or when you
>   select a Web site other than the first Web site listed. This can
>   happen in following two ways: Service handlers are not installed on
>   the first Web site that MDS is not attached to, but are installed on
>   another Web site that MDS is attached to. MDS will post an error
>   because it looks at the first Web site, not the second Web site. This
>   is a false negative, in that the error message indicates that the
>   handler mappings are not made, whereas they actually are. In this
>   case, you can ignore the error and proceed. Service handlers are
>   installed on the first Web site that MDS is not attached to, but are
>   not installed on another Web site that MDS is attached to. MDS will
>   not post an error because it looks at the first Web site, not the
>   second Web site. This is a false positive, because the lack of handler
>   mappings will cause MDS not to work. You should install the handler
>   mappings for the Web site that you are attaching MDS to.